# In C# what is best practice when setting up a project with dependencies (e.g. class library or separate files)

Tags: c#, dll

Lets say I have two projects.

- a main project that needs files from the secondary project (lets call this the library)
- a project (the library) containing multiple files that I could use in my main project (lets say it has 100 classes available).

Now I could create a C# class library (.dll) and reference it from my main project.
And all the functionality is available.

But what if my main project only needs 25 classes from the total 100 available. For the current situation that is an overhead and in my opinion I would be better of with direct file referencing from the other projects.

What would be the better of those two options (.dll or referencing the source code files in the library) and why?

Comment: If those 25 classes are completely independent of anything else in that dll, then why not put them in a separate dll and reference that from both solutions? That said, if you don't use anything from the 75 other classes, then they shouldn't even be jitted. So other than the dll being a few bytes bigger, that shouldn't impact runtime performance. And lastly, how do you plan on "referencing the source code files"?

Comment: Corak what I meant with referencing the source code files is the following: when adding an existing file you can either add or add as link. If you add them a copy is being made of the existing file and added to the project. When you add them as link a reference is being made to those file added by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say create a library (dll) and reference that. In that way the library can be used by multiple projects and you will have a single code base maintaining the library.

There is always that specific situation where you might end up in referencing the whole library and only using one class out of it.

Answer (score 3):

The class library is fine and I don't believe only utilizing 25/100 of the classes is really any overhead at all.  If you are truly using only 25 of all the classes in the library, then you will need to determine if those 25 class are all related and therefore better suited to be encased in their own project/dll.  You can still have a single solution for your class libraries, but have different projects based on function of the classes in each.